# How do I convert a mergesort accepting array to array of structures

Tags: c, data-structures

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>   
  struct Employ
 {
int id,age;
char name[100],desg[100];
char sec;
};
void mergeSort(struct Empoly emp,int low,int mid,int high)
{
int i, j, k, l, b[50];

l = low;
i = low;
j = mid + 1;
while ((l <= mid) && (j <= high))
{
    if (a[l] <= emp[j])
    {
        b[i] = emp[l];
        l++;
    }
    else
    {
        b[i] = a[j];
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
if (l > mid)
{
    for (k = j; k <= high; k++)
    {
        b[i] = a[k];
        i++;
    }
}
else
{
    for (k = l; k <= mid; k++)
    {
         b[i] = a[k];
         i++;
    }
}

for (k = low; k <= high; k++)
{
    a[k] = b[k];
}
}
```

*This part of the code does the merge sort by putting into an auxiliary array*

```
  void merge(struct Empoly emp,int low,int high)
  {
 int mid;

if(low < high)
{
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    merge(a, low, mid);
    merge(a, mid + 1, high);
    mergeSort(a, low, mid, high);
}


 void rd(struct Employ emp[], int n)
 {
int i;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("\nEmployee id: ");
    scanf("%d", &emp[i].id);
    printf("Employee name: ");
    scanf("%s", emp[i].name);
    printf("Employee age: ");
    scanf("%d", &emp[i].age);
    printf("Designation: ");
    scanf("%s", &emp[i].desg);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("GRade:  ");
    scanf("%c",&emp[i].sec);
    }

    printf("\nEntered details \n");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("\nEmployee Id:   %d\n", emp[i].id);
    printf("Name: %s\n", emp[i].name);
    printf("Age:  %d\n", emp[i].age);
    printf("Designation:   %s\n", emp[i].desg);
    printf("grade : %c", emp[i].sec);
}
printf("\n\n");
}

int main() 
{
struct Employ emp[10];
int n, ch, fg = 0, id,age,in; 
int i;
int mid;
char name[100];
do
{

    printf("Press 1 --- to input data\n");
    printf("Press 2 ---- to do mergesort\n");
    printf("Enter your'e choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            fg=0;
            while(fg==0)
            {
                printf("Enter the total number of employees: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                if(n>=1 && n<=10)
                    fg = 1;
                else
                    printf("Invalid input\n");                        
             }
            rd(emp, n);
           case 2:
       merge(emp, 0, n - 1);
     printf("The sorted array\n");
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     printf("%d\t",emp[i].age);
  printf("\n\n\n"); 
  break;    
  }
```

The main problem is linking the different structure variables like for example if I want a name to be sorted what all changes I have to do change to the code so it takes to age as an array of strucuture into the mergesort function.Also using char array what should I change.
**I want the age to be in sorted order using mergesort.**

Comment: Where is the _array to array of struct_ defined?  And how/where is the function that will pass the array called?  Show it in your posted code.  Its always faster and better for everyone (including you)  if you take the time to form your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: `struct Empoly emp` declares `emp` as a (one) structure, not a pointer (in)to an array of them.

Comment: If you have a working merge sort for arrays of `int`, but you want one for an array of `struct Empoly`, then you can get a long way towards that goal just by changing `int` to `struct Empoly` wherever the former represents the type of the objects being sorted.

Comment: The main other thing to do is to rewrite the element comparisons in terms of members of the structures.  I would consider writing a separate function for that, especially if you plan to use more than one member to determine relative element order.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried that but I still have errors

Comment: @matrix, the code presented in the question does not exhibit the form I would expect to result from a conversion such as I describe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what shd I do to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted had some serious problems. It was not even compiling let alone modifying `mergeSort()` for an array of struct.

The problems were:

1. no `break;` statement after `case 1:`
2. no `default:` case
3. incorrect function call to `merge()` function
4. if the user calls `merge()` function without first entering data in `emp` array, so initialize `n = 0`
5. no exit condition if you want to exit from do-while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Employ
{
    int id, age;
    char name[100], desg[100];
    char sec;
};

void mergeSort(struct Employ emp[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    // Here you need a temporary array of type struct like below
    struct Employ b[50];
    l = low;
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while ((l <= mid) && (j <= high))
    {
        /*
        the if condition below decides on which parameter
        the sorting is done. Age is used below.
        For sorting by name in alphabetical order, use stcmp() function
        if (strcmp(emp[l].name, emp[j].name)<=0)
        */
        if (emp[l].age <= emp[j].age)
        {
            b[i] = emp[l];
            l++;
        }
        else
        {
            b[i] = emp[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (l > mid)
    {
        for (k = j; k <= high; k++)
        {
            b[i] = emp[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (k = l; k <= mid; k++)
        {
             b[i] = emp[k];
             i++;
        }
    }

    for (k = low; k <= high; k++)
    {
        emp[k] = b[k];
    }
}

void merge(struct Employ emp[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge(emp, low, mid);
        merge(emp, mid + 1, high);
        mergeSort(emp, low, mid, high);
    }
}


void rd(struct Employ emp[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEmployee id: ");
        scanf("%d", &emp[i].id);
        printf("Employee name: ");
        scanf("%s", emp[i].name);
        printf("Employee age: ");
        scanf("%d", &emp[i].age);
        printf("Designation: ");
        scanf("%s", &emp[i].desg);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("GRade:  ");
        scanf(" %c",&emp[i].sec);
    }

    printf("\nEntered details \n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEmployee Id:   %d\n", emp[i].id);
        printf("Name: %s\n", emp[i].name);
        printf("Age:  %d\n", emp[i].age);
        printf("Designation:   %s\n", emp[i].desg);
        printf("grade : %c", emp[i].sec);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct Employ emp[10];
    int n=0, ch, fg = 0, id, age, in;
    int i;
    int mid;
    char name[100];
    do
    {
        printf("Press 0 --- to end the program\n");
        printf("Press 1 --- to input data\n");
        printf("Press 2 ---- to do mergesort\n");
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("\n\n-----------Program ended----------\n\n");
                return 0;
            case 1:
                fg=0;
                while(fg==0)
                {
                    printf("Enter the total number of employees: ");
                    scanf("%d", &n);
                    if(n>=1 && n<=10)
                        fg = 1;
                    else
                        printf("Invalid input\n");
                }
                rd(emp, n);
                break;
            case 2:
                merge(emp, 0, n - 1);
                printf("The sorted array\n");
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    printf("%d\t",emp[i].age);
                printf("\n\n\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Incorrect choice\n");
        }
    }while(1);
}
```

```
Input/Output example:

Press 0 --- to end the program
Press 1 --- to input data
Press 2 ---- to do mergesort
Enter your choice
1
Enter the total number of employees: 3
Employee Id:   1
Name: abc1
Age:  25
Designation:   xyz
grade : A
Employee Id:   2
Name: abc1
Age:  45
Designation:   xyz
grade : A
Employee Id:   3
Name: abc3
Age:  12
Designation:   xyz
grade : A

Press 0 --- to end the program
Press 1 --- to input data
Press 2 ---- to do mergesort
Enter your choice
2
The sorted array
12  25  45  


Press 0 --- to end the program
Press 1 --- to input data
Press 2 ---- to do mergesort
Enter your choice
33
Incorrect choice
Press 0 --- to end the program
Press 1 --- to input data
Press 2 ---- to do mergesort
Enter your choice
0


-----------Program ended----------
```

Comment: @matrix My pleasure. If it helped you, you can consider upvoting and accepting the answer:).